# Contenedor con scroll vertical toma como hijo a un hermano

Tags: php, html, css, bootstrap

Tengo un problema, es que tengo un div con un scroll vertical dentro de una card de bootstrap, tiene un hermano que tiene un input y un boton para enviar un mensaje (es un chat), pero el navegador toma a este este hermano, el que tiene el input, como hijo del div con scroll cuando son hermanos y son hijos de la card. (dejare incluso un poco de php por si tiene algo que ver, no tengo ni idea)

```
<div class="card">
    <h5 class="card-header">Chat de: <strong>User</strong></h5>
    <div class="card-body">
        <div style="height: 25em; overflow-y: scroll; margin-bottom: 1em;" class="container_chat">
            <?php while ($msg = mysqli_fetch_array($process_msg)) { ?>
            <div class="msgs" style="height: auto;">

                <?php if ($user_id == $msg['para']) { ?>
                <div class="msg1 d-flex align-items-center my-1">
                    <img src="iconos/interfaz.png" alt="" class="rounded-circle"
                        style="width:50px; background-color: gray;">
                    <p class="alert-secondary p-2 m-0 ml-2" style="border-radius:15px;"><?php echo $msg['msg']; ?></p>
                </div>
                <?php } else { ?>
                <div class="msg2 d-flex my-1 mr-4 align-items-center justify-content-end">
                    <p class="alert-primary p-2 mr-2 m-0 " style="border-radius:15px;"><?php echo $msg['msg']; ?></p>
                    <img src="iconos/interfaz.png" alt="" class="rounded-circle"
                        style="width:50px; background-color: gray;">
                </div>
            </div>
            <?php }} ?>
        </div>

        <div class="write">
            <form action="send_msg.php" method="POST">
                <div class="input-group">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Escriba un mensaje"
                        aria-label="Recipient's username" aria-describedby="button-addon2" name="msg">
                    <div class="input-group-append">
                    </div>
                    <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $chat_id; ?>">
                    <input type="hidden" name="de" value="<?php echo $user_id; ?>">
                    <input type="hidden" name="para" value="<?php echo $para; ?>">
                    <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Enviar</button>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como pueden ver el navegador encierra todo dentro de el div con scrollbar (container_chat), no se que hacer, esto hace que cuando hagas scroll hacia arriba se oculte el input cuando hay muchos mensajes. Gracias

Comment: comprueba tu código, puedes tener un `</div>` de mas que te genere ese problema

Answer (score 3):

El problema está en el `if..else`. Si te fijas el `if` abre un `div` y cierra un `div`, pero el else abre un `div` y cierra dos. El  segundo cierre de `div` pertenece al contenedor del `if..else`  y debería estar fuera del `else`.

Ahora mismo tienes esto (le cambié la indentación para que se vea mejor):

```php
<?php while ($msg = mysqli_fetch_array($process_msg)) { ?>
  <div class="msgs" style="height: auto;">

    <?php if ($user_id == $msg['para']) { ?>
      <div class="msg1 d-flex align-items-center my-1">
        <img src="iconos/interfaz.png" alt="" class="rounded-circle" style="width:50px; background-color: gray;">
        <p class="alert-secondary p-2 m-0 ml-2" style="border-radius:15px;"><?php echo $msg['msg']; ?></p>
      </div>
    <?php } else { ?>
      <div class="msg2 d-flex my-1 mr-4 align-items-center justify-content-end">
        <p class="alert-primary p-2 mr-2 m-0 " style="border-radius:15px;"><?php echo $msg['msg']; ?></p>
        <img src="iconos/interfaz.png" alt="" class="rounded-circle" style="width:50px; background-color: gray;">
      </div>
    </div>
  <?php }} ?>
```

Ese último `</div>` es el problema y debería ir fuera de la primera llave (`else`) y antes de la segunda (`while`), tal que así:

```php
<?php while ($msg = mysqli_fetch_array($process_msg)) { ?>
  <div class="msgs" style="height: auto;">

    <?php if ($user_id == $msg['para']) { ?>
      <div class="msg1 d-flex align-items-center my-1">
        <img src="iconos/interfaz.png" alt="" class="rounded-circle" style="width:50px; background-color: gray;">
        <p class="alert-secondary p-2 m-0 ml-2" style="border-radius:15px;"><?php echo $msg['msg']; ?></p>
      </div>
    <?php } else { ?>
      <div class="msg2 d-flex my-1 mr-4 align-items-center justify-content-end">
        <p class="alert-primary p-2 mr-2 m-0 " style="border-radius:15px;"><?php echo $msg['msg']; ?></p>
        <img src="iconos/interfaz.png" alt="" class="rounded-circle" style="width:50px; background-color: gray;">
      </div>
    <?php } ?>

  </div>
<?php } ?>
```